# Unity NavMesh Agent navigation tab not showing all settings

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

So I use in my unity game NavMesh agents, and I updated my unity version to 2023.3.0a5 for a specific package related to multiplayer. After I updated the version When I open the navigstion tab I can only see these settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Olq.png)
Agents and Areas, where if I search online for help about the navmesh agents I can see more settings like Bake and Object like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tWWi.png)
Can someone assist me in accessing the additional settings? I need to use the bake feature, but I'm currently unable to.

I tried to delete the surface that my navmesh agent was standing on, but the navmesh agent's navigation area didn't change by it.

Comment: the new navmesh is different its on the components now

Comment: So now I just bake each component individually?

Comment: you bake on the surface